# How would I edit a specific line in a text file with java?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that lets the user enter up to 9999 accounts into a text file, however the issue i'm having is that they can be put in any order, but I have to print them in a sequential order. Here's my code

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
public class CreateBankFile {

    public static int lines = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path file = Paths.get("/root/sandbox/BankAccounts.txt");

        String line = "";
        int acctNum = 0;
        String lastName;
        double bal;
        final int QUIT = 9999;

        try
        {
            OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));

            while(acctNum != QUIT)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the acct num less than 9999: ");
                acctNum = input.nextInt();
                if(acctNum == QUIT)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("Enter a last name: ");
                lastName = input.next();
                if(lastName.length() != 8)
                {
                    if(lastName.length() > 8)
                    {
                        lastName = lastName.substring(0, 8);
                    }
                    else if(lastName.length() < 8)
                    {
                        int diff = 8 - lastName.length();
                        for(int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
                        {
                            lastName += " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("Enter balance: ");
                bal = input.nextDouble();

                line = "ID#" + acctNum + "  " + lastName + "$" + bal;

                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();

                lines++;
            }
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

My question being, how can I get it so that when the user inputs "55" for example, it is printed to the 55th line of the text file?

Comment: You might manage the accounts in-memory using `Map<Intger,String>` where the key is the line number and the value is the line content, given that you need to initialize it from the file and adding an empty line for not entered accounts, even better if you ceate a class for the account and use in the map value!

Comment: @EhabQadah how would I initalize it from the file and add empty lines? Just a for loop going between the last entered acct and the line I wanted writing empty lines?

Comment: you read the file and based the line count and content you initialize the map, and when the user enters acctNum you update the `map.put(acctNum, account line)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

1) create a class that will store your line ( acctNum , lastName .. etc )

2) in your method , create an arraylist of the class you created , for a given number "n" , your method will parse all the lines , if acctNum is less than "n" , you will create a new instance using this line and add it to your arraylist

3) you will sort the arraylist using the acctNum and then print its content

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps FileChannels would work for you:

```
RandomAccessFile writer = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
FileChannel channel = writer.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap("Test write".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

channel.write(buff,5);//5 is the distance in the file
```

Lots of good examples on the web.

Answer (score 0):

In your question I think you are taking acctNum as line number and you want to add a line at this line number in the file so you can do something like this.

```java
    List<String> readLines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    readLines.set(acctNum- 1, data);
    Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I assumed that you are using Java 7 or higher so I did `acctNum-1` because in Java 7 or higher version line number starts with 1 in rest it starts with 0 so you can change to `acctNum`.
**Reference:** [List set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [NIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)